# What is the generic name for “decimal” type fractions?

Tags: fractions, decimal-expansion

A number in the form:

```
1.234
```

is often loosely called **decimal**, though the name really refers to the fact that its base is 10, and has nothing to do with the faction part.

A binary number in the form:

```
1.0101
```

follows the same principal, but, obviously it can’t be called a decimal. The same would apply to numbers of any other base.

Is there a proper generic name for fractions expressed using this notation?

Answer (score 1):

$1.234$ is a decimal *fraction*, in the sense that it's $\dfrac{1234}{10^3}$.

So, $1.0101_2$ is a binary fraction, in the sense that it's $\dfrac{10101_2}{2^4}$.

Comment: Would that terminology be sufficient to distinguish it from, say, $\frac{101}{1011}$ which is also a binary fraction?

Comment: @Manngo, that terminology is used for fractions that have finite expansions.

Comment: It seems "binary fractions" are typically called [dyadic rationals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadic_rational).

Comment: Dyadic rationals means rational numbers whose denominator has the form $2^n$. Manngo's comment asks about general rational fractions whose numerator and denominator happen to be written in radix-2 notation. The example they give, $\frac{101}{1011}$, is not a dyadic rational.